# Buttons centered and side by side

Tags: html, css

I am having issues getting my buttons in the center of the screen and side by side. I have been only able to successfully get one of the other but not both. Currently with the below code the buttons are side by side, but stay at the top left corner of the screen. Below is the code I have currently set up. The commented out lines are just some things I have tried. Any help is appreciated.

```css
  body {
    background-image: url("KDHub_Wallpaper.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
    background-color: #00ADEF;
}

 .button {
 appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none; 
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 2px 8px;
   #margin: auto;
   #margin-top: 225px;
    #display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background-color: #941c2f;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
   #border:0;
   #border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
   #position: static;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
}

 .button:hover{
 background: #C1CFDA;
 color: black
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <title>KDHub</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <a href="https://test.url.com" class="button" target="_blank">Test 2</a>
  <a href="https:/test.url2.com" class="button" target="_blank">Test 2</a>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `margin-top` in conjunction with `position: static`, which won't work. You also appear to be attempting to control the positioning with `top: 50%` and `left: 50%`. `top` and `left` should be used with [**absolute positioning**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning), and `marign-top` should be used with [**relative positioning**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Relative_positioning).

It's easiest to achieve both horizontal and vertical centering with [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), utilising the `display: flex`, `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` property values. Note that you'll also need to specify a `height` property in order for flex to take effect:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
}
```

This can be seen working in the following example, where I've also fixed up the URL and some of the invalid properties (which were preceded with `#`):

```css
body {
  background-image: url("KDHub_Wallpaper.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: #00ADEF;
}

.button {
  appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #941c2f;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: static;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #C1CFDA;
  color: black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>KDHub</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="https://test.url.com" class="button" target="_blank">Test 2</a>
    <a href="https://test.url2.com" class="button" target="_blank">Test 2</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: SO I was able to use this one and get it to work exactly how I wanted. I modified it a little for my needs but it worked.  Below is what worked for me.                                                                                               
  .container {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS `flex`. You can learn more here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Added the following code in your css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("KDHub_Wallpaper.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: #00ADEF;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.button {
  appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  #margin: auto;
  #margin-top: 225px;
  #display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #941c2f;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  #border: 0;
  #border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  #position: static;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #C1CFDA;
  color: black
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>KDHub</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="https://test.url.com" class="button" target="_blank">Test 2</a>
    <a href="https:/test.url2.com" class="button" target="_blank">Test 2</a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This code also worked to center it horizontally, but it did not center it vertically to the middle of the page. :(

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine you just have to add text-align center in the parent element of the buttons to center the inline blocks

```css
  body {
    background-image: url("KDHub_Wallpaper.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
    background-color: #00ADEF;
}

/* Added */
.container{
text-align:center
}

 .button {
 appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none; 
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 2px 8px;
   #margin: auto;
   #margin-top: 225px;
    #display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background-color: #941c2f;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
   #border:0;
   #border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
   #position: static;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
}

 .button:hover{
 background: #C1CFDA;
 color: black
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <title>KDHub</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <a href="https://test.url.com" class="button" target="_blank">Test 2</a>
  <a href="https:/test.url2.com" class="button" target="_blank">Test 2</a>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked to center it horizontally, but it did not center it vertically to the middle of the page. :(

Comment: Add a parent div to the container with a height of 100vw and position set to relative. Set the container to position:absolute, top:50% and transform: translateY(-50%). It's is worth looking into flex box as one of the commenters suggests also